# Remix - Example MultiSigWallet - Invalid JSON RPC response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":5190687608070641}

Tags: solidity

Newbie here and post 2 on this multi-sig-wallet contract - I'm trying to understand intricacies and interactions between contracts.

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-sig-wallet/ has the main and test contracts:

```
contract MultiSigWallet {
    event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint amount, uint balance);
    event SubmitTransaction(
        address indexed owner,
        uint indexed txIndex,
        address indexed to,
        uint value,
        bytes data
    );
    event ConfirmTransaction(address indexed owner, uint indexed txIndex);
    event RevokeConfirmation(address indexed owner, uint indexed txIndex);
    event ExecuteTransaction(address indexed owner, uint indexed txIndex);

    address[] public owners;
    mapping(address => bool) public isOwner;
    uint public numConfirmationsRequired;

    struct Transaction {
        address to;
        uint value;
        bytes data;
        bool executed;
        uint numConfirmations;
    }

    // mapping from tx index => owner => bool
    mapping(uint => mapping(address => bool)) public isConfirmed;

    Transaction[] public transactions;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner[msg.sender], "not owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier txExists(uint _txIndex) {
        require(_txIndex < transactions.length, "tx does not exist");
        _;
    }

    modifier notExecuted(uint _txIndex) {
        require(!transactions[_txIndex].executed, "tx already executed");
        _;
    }

    modifier notConfirmed(uint _txIndex) {
        require(!isConfirmed[_txIndex][msg.sender], "tx already confirmed");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address[] memory _owners, uint _numConfirmationsRequired) {
        require(_owners.length > 0, "owners required");
        require(
            _numConfirmationsRequired > 0 &&
                _numConfirmationsRequired <= _owners.length,
            "invalid number of required confirmations"
        );

        for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; i++) {
            address owner = _owners[i];

            require(owner != address(0), "invalid owner");
            require(!isOwner[owner], "owner not unique");

            isOwner[owner] = true;
            owners.push(owner);
        }

        numConfirmationsRequired = _numConfirmationsRequired;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
    }

    function submitTransaction(
        address _to,
        uint _value,
        bytes memory _data
    ) public onlyOwner {
        uint txIndex = transactions.length;

        transactions.push(
            Transaction({
                to: _to,
                value: _value,
                data: _data,
                executed: false,
                numConfirmations: 0
            })
        );

        emit SubmitTransaction(msg.sender, txIndex, _to, _value, _data);
    }

    function confirmTransaction(
        uint _txIndex
    ) public onlyOwner txExists(_txIndex) notExecuted(_txIndex) notConfirmed(_txIndex) {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_txIndex];
        transaction.numConfirmations += 1;
        isConfirmed[_txIndex][msg.sender] = true;

        emit ConfirmTransaction(msg.sender, _txIndex);
    }

    function executeTransaction(
        uint _txIndex
    ) public onlyOwner txExists(_txIndex) notExecuted(_txIndex) {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_txIndex];

        require(
            transaction.numConfirmations >= numConfirmationsRequired,
            "cannot execute tx"
        );

        transaction.executed = true;

        (bool success, ) = transaction.to.call{value: transaction.value}(
            transaction.data
        );
        require(success, "tx failed");

        emit ExecuteTransaction(msg.sender, _txIndex);
    }

    function revokeConfirmation(
        uint _txIndex
    ) public onlyOwner txExists(_txIndex) notExecuted(_txIndex) {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_txIndex];

        require(isConfirmed[_txIndex][msg.sender], "tx not confirmed");

        transaction.numConfirmations -= 1;
        isConfirmed[_txIndex][msg.sender] = false;

        emit RevokeConfirmation(msg.sender, _txIndex);
    }

    function getOwners() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return owners;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return transactions.length;
    }

    function getTransaction(
        uint _txIndex
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            address to,
            uint value,
            bytes memory data,
            bool executed,
            uint numConfirmations
        )
    {
        Transaction storage transaction = transactions[_txIndex];

        return (
            transaction.to,
            transaction.value,
            transaction.data,
            transaction.executed,
            transaction.numConfirmations
        );
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    uint public i;

    function callMe(uint j) public {
        i += j;
    }

    function getData() public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(uint256)", 123);
    }
}
```

I'm working in Remix, using the Apex wallet with the `Injected Provider` using Goerli network.

I have executed `submitTransaction` passing data from `TestContract.getData`.  I can `getOwners(), getTransactionCount(), isConfirmed(), ..` and `confirmTransaction()` but when i try and execute `executeTransaction()` passing zero (0) for the `txIndex` (like in all the other function calls) it immediately pops ups with

[image]

Sending immediately fails and so there is no transaction with any further details.

But sending brings up this:

[image]

The error can be seen as `tx failed`, which is part of the function:

```
        (bool success, ) = transaction.to.call{value: transaction.value}(
            transaction.data
        );
        require(success, "tx failed");
```

But this is happening without the transaction being sent, so there is something known beforehand that causes the error.

The transaction looks ok:

```
0:address: to 0x8783746a70ABA0587f9C872Bf52f952E50208730
1:uint256: value 9
2:bytes: data 0xe73620c3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b
3:bool: executed false
4:uint256: numConfirmations 1
```

Any ideas?